# Is there an iPhone app for SharePoint Stack site?

Tags: feature-request

If not, request you to please provide it. I think Android app is available. It would be great if you develop iPhone app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is one that you can add any site from stack exchange...

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/six-to-eight/id384094708?mt=8

Comment: Just adding the link to the [StackApps page](http://stackapps.com/questions/623/six-to-eight-an-iphone-client-now-in-the-app-store) and the [official site](http://www.sixtoeightapp.com/)