# Is there an Android app for Stackexchange?

Tags: support

I've seen from another [question](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/676/is-there-an-iphone-app-for-sharepoint-stack-site) that there is an iPhone app so I just wondered if there was one for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Stack Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.b5d.android&hl=en).

Works for me, though to be honest I don't ever answer questions from the app.

I'll always hop on a browser and use a real keyboard.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, I don't think you CAN answer questions from the app. It does give a handy link to the full site, though.

Comment: Don't know, never tried.

Answer (score 3):

I read the answer you pointed to and did a search on stackapps.com that they refer to.

There are some apps there, but nothing as fancy as the iPhone one

https://stackapps.com/search?q=android

Comment: so now there is a worty IPhone version? must check again. Thanks for the reminder Anders.